# Why Does My Button Refuse To Relocate To Wanted Page

Tags: html, css

I was working on a quick and dirty project of mine and when it came to some of the buttons no matter what I did they would not work, I have tried to put them in an `<a>` tag but it messes up my CSS and isn't worth the extra trouble, anyone know what to do? (The YouTube URL is only there for testing purposes)

Here is my HTML:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
         <div class="header">
          <header>
                <input class="btn" type="button" value="Home"              id="button1" onsubmit=""/>
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Processors"        id="button2" onsubmit="" />
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Motherboards"      id="button3" onsubmit"" />
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Graphics Cards"    id="button4" onsubmit="https://www.youtube.com" />
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Power Supplys"     id="button5" onsubmit="" />
                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Website Inquires"  id="button6" onsubmit="" />
          </header>
         </div>
         
         <h1 class="title"> Personal Computers Technology </h1>
 
      <p><span class="paragraph"> Do you want to learn about computers? Do you not know where 
       to start? Well you have come to the right place! Here you will learn about the functionalities of a motherboard, what a processot is and what it does, how your graphics cards sends out video ouput. You will learn about what a power supoply does
       and why they very important. Lastly you will learn about storage and what the difference between an SSD an HDD   
      </span></p>


       <!-- Please try to avoid editing code under this line as much as possible-->
      <div class="container">

<img class="child" src= "https://cdn.glitch.com/8282fc98-4236-406a-9a5e-f9535f41553b%2FPC.jpg?v=1604156880410" width="300" height="200">
    
          </div>
          
      <!--I beg you dont tuch the code above this comment line-->

          <p><span class="secondParagraph">
            We are here to support your learning journey on computer parts. As may have most likely alreasdy noticed at 
            the top of the webpage we have direct links to all of the other educational content. If you do have any inquires
            feel free to leave us a notice and we will try to respond to it as fast as possible. Thank you and have a great learning experience.
          </span></p>


            <iframe width="350" height="250" class="video" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/8282fc98-4236-406a-9a5e-f9535f41553b%2FFROST%20Gaming%20PC%20-%20Time%20Lapse%20Build.mp4?v=1604766330602"  type="video/mp4"></iframe>
          
        </body>
    </html>
```

And my CSS:

```
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #e9e4dc;
}

.header {
  height: 4.6rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #555555;
  padding: 26px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #696969;
}

.btn:active {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.title {
  margin-left: 385px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -175px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 35px;
}

.paragraph {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.secondParagraph {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-left: 375px;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.video {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: -165px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The reason these don't work properly is simply because INPUT tags are a part of forms; even if you get it working its not optimized according to industry standards. Why not just use P tags and style them instead?

Comment: Fair point i'll try using that and seeing how it goes

Comment: ", I have tried to put them in an `<a>` tag but it messes up my CSS and isn't worth the extra trouble" - yes it is worth the trouble. `a` tags are designed for navigation and `buttons` are not. SEO crawlers will follow links in `a` tags but not buttons. Screen readers know how to handle links in `a` tags but not buttons. Use the right element for the job and then style with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copied what you have given for code and see what was wrong.

First off, I believe you are missing the first line in your .css file.

Second, I would change all of the

```
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Home" id="button1" onsubmit=""/>
```

to something like

```
<p class="btn"><a href="#">Yor Text Here</a></p>
```

and change the css for the btn to make it look like a button and how you wish. I recommend [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_horizontal.asp) to help you with the styling.